# need to add before and after disconnected html code like /div to an object

Tags: javascript, jquery

got a simple question! i have a code with structure like that:

```
    <a class="adv_link" target="_blank" href="">Link 1</a>
    text here 1
    <div class="adv_separator"></div>

    <a class="adv_link" target="_blank" href="">Link 2</a>
    text here 2
    <div class="adv_separator"></div>

and etc...
```

i want to add BEFORE EACH link with class "add_link" the code: `<div class="slide">` and add AFTER EACH div with class "adv_separator" the code: `</div>` how i can do it with jquery?

p.s. in other words i want to create several divs nested with these links,texts and divs so i can use jquery cycle plugin to create a slider.

thank you all for the help!

Comment: Is there an element which contains those? If there is it makes the code for this a lot simpler.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan no its generated from advertisement php code, i cant modify it in the way i want

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan nope ) the only parent div i added myself, but i also need inside divs nested with these links and text to create from it the slider.

Comment: So essentially you wish to wrap each `a.adv_link`, `textNode` and `div.adv_separator` in a `<div>` element?

Comment: @BenM yes, smth like this, if i understood u clear ))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple logic, but you have to know how the DOM works. (Append "moves" the element, there is no "sparse selector", you need to know where to place the new element, etc.)

```
$('.adv_link').each(function() {
    var el = $('<div></div>', {'class': 'slide'}),
        link = $(this),
        text = $(this.nextSibling),
        sep = link.nextUntil('.adv_separator');

    // Append each element. Cloned elements, of course.
    el
        .append(link.clone())
        .append(text.clone())
        .append(sep.clone());

    // Remove the separator and the text.
    sep.remove();
    text.remove();

    // And replace the link with the full div containing the cloned elements.
    link.replaceWith(el);            
});
```

Answer (score 4):

#### The very short version:

```
$(".adv_link").each(function() {
    $(this).nextUntil(".adv_separator +")
      .andSelf().add(this.nextSibling)
      .wrapAll("<div class='slide' />");
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsbin.com/ukafip/2/

Comment: Not sure that works, don't you end up with `<div class="slide"><a...>text<div class="sep"></div></a></div>`?

Comment: Must be because jQuery cleans up your HTML. (no div in an anchor, for example.) Nice find :-)